# Ansible Jinja2 always showing "Changed"

Tags: ansible, network-programming, jinja2, cisco-ios

I have a Jinja2 template I am using for Cisco IOS devices. Currently my playbook runs fine, but always shows "changed" despite there being no obvious changes... I ran with the verbose tag and received the output below, but didn't see anything obvious. Is this normal behavior, and if not does anyone know of a work around/better way to accomplish this?

Debug output:

```
changed: [Parakoopa891F] => {
    "banners": {},
    "changed": true,
    "commands": [
        "interface Vlan 200",
        "description DMZ created by Ansible",
        "ip address 10.200.200.254 255.255.255.0",
        "ip nat inside",
        "ip virtual-reassembly",
        "zone-member security INSIDE",
        "no shutdown",
        "interface Loopback 30",
        "description Loopback created by Ansible",
        "ip address 172.30.69.254 255.255.255.0",
        "ip nat inside",
        "ip virtual-reassembly",
        "zone-member security INSIDE",
        "no shutdown"
    ],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "after": null,
            "backup": false,
            "backup_options": null,
            "before": null,
            "defaults": false,
            "diff_against": null,
            "diff_ignore_lines": null,
            "intended_config": null,
            "lines": null,
            "match": "line",
            "multiline_delimiter": "@",
            "parents": null,
            "provider": null,
            "replace": "line",
            "running_config": null,
            "save_when": "never",
            "src": "interface Vlan 200\n  description DMZ created by Ansible\n  ip address 10.200.200.254 255.255.255.0\n  ip nat inside\n  ip virtual-reassembly\n  zone-member security INSIDE\n    no shutdown\n  interface Loopback 30\n  description Loopback created by Ansible\n  ip address 172.30.69.254 255.255.255.0\n  ip nat inside\n  ip virtual-reassembly\n  zone-member security INSIDE\n    no shutdown\n  "
        }
    },
    "updates": [
        "interface Vlan 200",
        "description DMZ created by Ansible",
        "ip address 10.200.200.254 255.255.255.0",
        "ip nat inside",
        "ip virtual-reassembly",
        "zone-member security INSIDE",
        "no shutdown",
        "interface Loopback 30",
        "description Loopback created by Ansible",
        "ip address 172.30.69.254 255.255.255.0",
        "ip nat inside",
        "ip virtual-reassembly",
        "zone-member security INSIDE",
        "no shutdown"
    ]
}
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- name: "Set Router Configuration"
  hosts: routers
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: "Apply router config"
      ios_config:
        src: "templates/{{ vendor }}_template.j2"
      when: "'{{ vendor }}' == 'cisco'"
```

Jinja2 template

```
interface Vlan 200
  description {{ interfaces.vlans.dmz.description }}
  ip address {{ interfaces.vlans.dmz.ip }}
  ip nat {{ interfaces.vlans.dmz.nat }}
  ip virtual-reassembly
  zone-member security {{ interfaces.vlans.dmz.zone }}
  {% if 'up' in interfaces.vlans.dmz.status %}
  no shutdown
  {% else %}
  shutdown
  {% endif %}
interface Loopback {{ interfaces.loopbacks.test.number}}
  description {{ interfaces.loopbacks.test.description }}
  ip address {{ interfaces.loopbacks.test.ip }}
  ip nat {{ interfaces.loopbacks.test.nat }}
  ip virtual-reassembly
  zone-member security {{ interfaces.loopbacks.test.zone }}
  {% if 'up' in interfaces.loopbacks.test.status %}
  no shutdown
  {% else %}
  shutdown
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: I can't immediately tell if this applies to you, but there's a suspiciously relevant looking [FAQ entry about always changed tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/network/user_guide/faq.html#why-do-the-config-modules-always-return-changed-true-with-abbreviated-commands)

Comment: Fix the condition `when: vendor == "cisco"`

Comment: Tried changing the syntax, but the result is the same. The way it is listed in my question still functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got to the bottom of this, but I too had a similar issue with my Jinja templates. To resolve it you need to address the whitespace control. `if` and `for` statements can add undesirable whitespace, which may not be the same every time so ansible detects a change. To make it Idempotent you can add to the top of each of your templates:

```
#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: True, trim_blocks: True
```

Though I think ansible uses trim_blocks by default.

I recommend testing the template using the following online Jinja2 parser and renderer by TTL255: https://j2live.ttl255.com/

Some reading on the subject:
https://blog.networktocode.com/post/whitespace-control-in-jinja-templates/
https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-3-whitespace-control/